# Mix blend mood with black text

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello there i'm trying to achieve the following effect in this [website](https://mouthwash.co/)

which is blending black text on scrolling using mix blend mode
i inspected the code and tried to copy it but it's ofc not working fine
here is my code

```css
.nav {
  width: 95vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-size: 3vw;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
.nav__item {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
  <a href="" class="nav__item">home</a>
  <a href="" class="nav__item">articles</a>
  <a href="" class="nav__item">info</a>
</nav>

<section class="hero">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1589362086172-2c29bea70386?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=668&q=80" alt="">
</section>
```

the issue here i want the text to be black not white, i inspected the code he sets the color to links to be white but it's black on the screen, does it involve js ?

Comment: The text would be black if it was on a white background. It's the difference. The reason you can't use black text on white is 255-0 = 255 *(white still)*.

Comment: Can you guide me how to do that ?

Comment: Oh, I was just explaining when using `mix-blend-mode: difference;`, that you have to use white text to get black. RGB *(red, green, blue)* is (0 to 255, 0 to 255, 0 to 255), so white is (255,255,255), and black is (0,0,0). Background color - text color = new color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a container for the whole page then set its background color in CSS to something, like white. Here's an example

```css
.nav {
  width: 95vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-size: 3vw;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
.nav__item {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.container {
background-color: white;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<nav class="nav">
  <a href="" class="nav__item">home</a>
  <a href="" class="nav__item">articles</a>
  <a href="" class="nav__item">info</a>
</nav>

<section class="hero">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1589362086172-2c29bea70386?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=668&q=80" alt="">
</section>

 Run code snippet
 </div>
```

Comment: thx guyz for your comments, by none you answered the main question how to keep the text black ? can you please check the website, and excuse my ignorance

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, you want your text to change color or do you want it to stay black?  if you want it to stay black then remove the mix-blend-mode: difference; and set your .nav__item color to black.

Comment: i want the achieve the same exact thing as the website i put to make it more simple to understand me, sorry for my english

Comment: My code is exactly that.  Click "Run code snippet" then click "full page" and you will see that it works.

Answer (score 2):

Consider your Browser uses colors based on RGB *(Red, Green, Blue)*, which each take a number between 0 and 255. 256^3 = ‭16,777,216‬ colors. CSS `mix-blend-mode: difference;` gives you the absolute value *(distance from zero)* of the `background-color` minus the `color`. If you have a white background, it is represented as `rgb(255,255,255)`. If your text is black you would have a color of `rgb(0,0,0)`, so if each column *(color)* is subtracted, and you get the absolute value, you get `rgb(255,255,255)`, so the text would still be white on white. If your text is white `rgb(255,255,255)` and you subtract `rgb(0,0,0)` and get the absolute value, you get black on white. If your background was black `rgb(0,0,0)` and your text was white `rgb(255,255,255)`, you get white text. What does this mean to you? You will have to have white text if you want the true difference in colors, when using `mix-blend-mode: difference;`. Your issue looks to be that you haven't set a `background-color` on the `body`, though. They don't do an absolute difference on the alpha-channel, and default `background-color` is `transparent`.

Answer (score 0):

**We need to add some white color thing (white color text or white color shape) under the navbar to see it. I have added some white text under the nav. It is working. 

see the below example.**

```css
.nav {
    width: 95vw;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    font-size: 6vw;
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.nav__item {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.hero {
    height: 200vh;
}

.hero .box-1 {
    position: absolute;
    background: black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    left: 0;
    top: 100px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
    <a href="" class="nav__item">home</a>
    <a href="" class="nav__item">articles</a>
    <a href="" class="nav__item">info</a>
</nav>

<section class="hero">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1589362086172-2c29bea70386?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=668&q=80" alt="">
    <div class="box-1">test  test test</div>
</section>
```